# Detailed, tecnical documentation of Linux/UNIX filesystems?

Tags: linux, filesystems

I want to uniderstand in more detail how filesystems work - not how to use them, but how they are laid out on disk. Ideally, to such an extent that I could inspect a disk device with a hex editor and understand what I see - in the past I've got as far as 'inodes', but in most cases it goes a bit vague after that, and I can understand why, since there are so many different filesystems.

This is not for any purpose other than curiosity; and who knows, it might become useful. So, is there any good documentation or discussion of these subjects somewhere? Or is it back to kernel sources?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The kernel itself [includes a fair amount of file system documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems), more or less detailed. [The ext4 documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/ext4/) includes a description of the layout (converted from [the wiki](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout) a few years ago).

Other file systems are documented elsewhere, for example in [XFS Algorithms & Data Structures](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/fs/xfs/docs/xfs_filesystem_structure.pdf) for XFS, along with [the XFS Linux wiki](https://xfs.wiki.kernel.org/), or [the Btrfs wiki](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) for Btrfs. Many file systems are documented [in academic papers](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=linux%20filesystems).